# XSLT character-escaping query

Tags: xslt

Lets say I have the following code snippet below, how do I also apply the disable-output-escaping to the {name} in the title attribute?

```
<a title="{name}"><xsl:value-of select="name" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></a>
```

This has really got me stumped.

Thanks guys.

Comment: @James: As jelovirt pointed out this is not supported by XSLT. What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done with XSLT. The [spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#disable-output-escaping):

> It is an error for output escaping to
>   be disabled for a text node that is
>   used for something other than a text
>   node in the result tree.

Thus it makes no difference if you use Attribute Value Templates or `xsl:attribute` with `xsl:value-of`, because you're generating an attribute node, not a text node. It's a limitation in the language.

Answer (score 0):

You can't as is. The {name} shortcut doesn't allow additional parameters. Use the <xsl:attribute> tag instead.